# iPod Nano 5th Gen and an old G4

Tags: ipod, g4, osx-panther

I want to buy my dad an iPod nano for christmas.
All he has for a computer is an old G4 that is still running Mac OS X 10.3.x (10.3.9 probably)

What iPod can I buy him and he still be able to use? The newest nano requires iTunes 9 which he cannot run.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your dads PC:
1.6 GHz Atom z230 CPU
1 GB RAM
nVidia ION Graphics
160 GB HDD
Windows XP Home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Nano#Specifications).  According to the chart only the 1st and 2nd Gen nano's will work in 10.3.x.

A G4 should be able to run 10.4 (or even 10.5 although if it came running 10.3 it's probably too old).  So you could upgrade his OS and accoring the chart 10.4 is enough for any current nano.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be perfect to him:

http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&client=firefox&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&q=ipod+60+GB&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=pO0PS6yIAoiimwPo-dnUAg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CC0QrQQwAw

Or try some old shuffles

Comment: So a old classic ipod is probably the best bet?

Comment: Exactly. I'm using it, but for 80GB. It is perfect for me, and it will be perfect for your dad. Believe me.

Comment: What about a ipod nano 3rd or 4th gen. Would that work on 10.3.9?

Comment: not sure about it. I suppose yes.